# Python selenium find element by certain innerHTML and then a parent and child

Tags: python, selenium

Currently I am trying to find a certain element on the website which can be identified by its inner html. After I find this item I need to find its parent and a child.

Here is the example, I need to populate the `textarea` with different content, the only way I can find the correct `textarea` is finding the needed `td` which can be identified by its `innerHTML`

```
<tr>
  <td class="alignRight"> 1 </td>
  <textarea></textarea>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="alignRight"> 2 </td>
  <textarea></textarea>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="alignRight"> 3 </td>
  <textarea></textarea>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="alignRight"> 4 </td>
  <textarea></textarea>
</tr>
```

I have tryed a few solutions but so far no results, the closest I got is this:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('td.alignRight').get_attribute('innerHTML')
print (elem, type(elem))
```

The problem here is it finds only the first element. The best thing would be if I could directly find the **element WHERE innterHTML = Value**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use below code to get required `texarea` by preceding sibling `td` with specific `value`:

```
value = "1"
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[.='%s']/following-sibling::textarea" % value)
```

Comment: Had to modify it, because you missed the parent elem, but it helped me a lot, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familar with `python` but I can explain the logic:-

1. Create dynamic Xpath to find out sibling node of required node using value[1,2,3], where you can send value as parameter.
2. Find out parent node using xpath.
3. Find the child are using `tagname`

I tried writing code, syntax may be incorrect.

```
value="what ever value you want to provide[1,2,]"
requiredXpath=".//td[@class='alignRight' and text()="+value+"]"
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(requiredXpath).find_element_by_xpath("..").find_element_by_tag_name("textarea)
```